# Why is this \def failing?

Tags: definition

This is just a small snippet, for debugging:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\block#1{\begin{array}{ll}\ &{#1}\end{array}}
\def\sub#1#2{\text{#1}:\\\block{#2}}

\begin{document}

$\sub{If $A$}{\sub{If $B$}{...} \\ \sub{If $\lnot B$}{...}} \\ \sub{If $\neg A$}{...}$

\end{document}
```

When I try to run `latex` on this, I get:

```
% latex debug.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./debug.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (./debug.aux)
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.11 ...b{If $B$}{...} \\ \sub{If $\lnot B$}{...}}
                                                   \\ \sub{If $\neg A$}{...}
? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on debug.log.
```

What is wrong in the source code?

**EDIT:** the results should look like this:

[image]

Comment: it is unrelated to your definition, you have used `\text` without defining it. Did you mean to include `\usepackage{amsmath}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you so much for pointing this out.  Indeed, the original I got this from (and which was *also* failing) had the command you mentioned.  I will update my post.  Sorry for the botched question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: OK, I've fixed the incorrect description.

Comment: It's really hard to guess what that code is supposed to generate.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion with the two embedded `\sub` commands. As @egreg said, it's hard to guess what it's supposed to do... Are those two `\sub` really intended to be embedded? If I separate them it compiles fine.

Comment: @egreg: sorry, I've added a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\def` should not be used in latex documents and it is very hard to guess the intention here as you give no indication of the desired ouput, but the braces in `{#1}`can do  nothing useful, and will generate errors as you show. If they are removed you get

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\block#1{\begin{array}{ll}\ &#1\end{array}}
\def\sub#1#2{\text{#1}:\\\block{#2}}

\begin{document}

$\sub{If $A$}{\sub{If $B$}{...} \\ \sub{If $\lnot B$}{...}} \\ \sub{If $\neg A$}{...}$

\end{document}
```